# How to handle SharePlay initiated via AirPlay Button

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, airplay, shareplay

We recently implemented SharePlay in our broadcasting app and most of things work fine.

We now found out, that the user, during a SharePlay session, is able to hand over the session to an Apple TV via the AirPlay Button, which is convenient UX, because during the SharePlay session, this should be exactly what the user had in mind.

However, since this is not the start of a "real" or "normal" AirPlay, things are different: Especially `AVPlayer`s `isExternalPlaybackActive` property doesn't change in case it's a SharePlay handover. This leads to problems in our app with AirPlay and SharePlay behaviour. Most of all, the user cannot control the playback (pause, seek) anymore from his device, but only from her/his Apple TV, only other participants of the SharePlay session can.

How can we detect the handover to Apple TV?

Is there an alternative to `isExternalPlaybackActive` for the SharePlay case?